# Is there a way to actually execute a DDL update with liquibase-maven-plugin?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm new to liquibase and I am wondering whether it is possible to actually execute a changeset.

update/updateSQL goal seem to simply generate a SQL file with all SQL commands (https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_updatesql.html)

And from other research I've learned that there's no such thing as a dry run ([Liquibase - generate script without applying changesets to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941876/liquibase-generate-script-without-applying-changesets-to-database) / [Does Liquibase support dry run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847482/does-liquibase-support-dry-run)) because as indicated above, update will only create SQL scripts.

So my assumption would be that liquibase never actually executes DDL/Changes.

Please note that we're on MySQL.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect. The `update` command will actually apply the changes to the database. The `updateSQL` is there to generate the SQL that would be applied, for use when you can't run Liquibase in a certain environment (i.e. your DBAs won't let you run Liquibase in production) or to preview the SQL before applying it.

There are some demos showing the basic workflow in the [Liquibase YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5qMsRjObu685rTBq0PJX8w).